# Confusion in Combinatorics-Problem (Truncated Lattice Walk)

Tags: combinatorics

> **Question:** How many routes are there from $A$ to $B$ along the grid in the diagram below? You can only move upwards or to the right until you reach $B$.

[image: Diagram 1]
I started off by listing some paths that *will* get me to $B$. I started listing them off...\begin{align*} & \text{UUURRUURRUURRR}\\ & \text{UUURRRUURUURRR}\\ & \text{UURRUUURRURRRU}\\\vdots\end{align*}
Soon, I realized that this was a simple counting problem. So I got$$\binom{14}{7}=\text{Some large number greater than 2000}$$
But the answer was exactly $2000$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: you are going further, see that the path RRRRRRRUUUUUUU is possible in the binomial but not in the graph

Comment: @Phicar Ooohhh.... Then *how* would you solve this?

Comment: Do the same analysis but you have to go to the cut points of the graph, say $(4,3),(3,4)$(read them as it where in the plane) etc..You have to pass by those points.

Comment: Also notice that there is a symettry by the middle So just do it to the cut points below the diagonal and multiply by 2. You will end up with something like $2\binom{5}{3}^3$

Comment: @Phicar - Very nice closed form. You should post this as a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

Refer to the diagram above.

Denote $\vec{XY}_Z$ as the number of ways to move from point $X$ to point $Y$ moving through optional point $Z$.
We want to find $\vec{AB}$.

First we consider the number of paths through $C$, i.e. $\vec{AB}_C$.  The problem can be simplified by superimposing several $2\times 3$ hexominoes (shown in red) on the original and extended lattice.

$\vec{AB}_C$ can be computed as a product of several subpaths as follows (* indicates multiply):
$$\vec{AB}_C=\vec{AC}*\left[\vec{CE}* \vec{EB}+\vec{CF}*\vec{FB}\right]$$

Note that

- $\vec{CE}+\vec{CF}=\vec{CG}$ (by symmetry and also because $G$ is one step away from $E,F$) and
- $\vec{FB}=\vec{EB}=\vec{GH}$ (moving green squares to blue squares on lattice extension).

Hence 
$$\vec{AB}_C=\vec{AC}*[(\vec{CE}+\vec{CF})*\vec{GH}]=\vec{AC}*\vec{CG}*\vec{GH}=\binom 52^3$$

By symmetry along diagonal $AB$, it is obvious that $\vec{AB}_D=\vec{AB}_C$. A similar but orthogonal set of hexominoes can be drawn for $\vec{AB}_D$.

Hence the total number of paths from $A$ to $B$ is given as

$$\vec{AB}=\vec{AB}_C+\vec{AB}_D=\color{red}{2\binom 52^3=2000}$$

---

**General Case**

For a similar configuration of $3$ lattices each of dimension $n\times n$ and overlapping by one square along a common diagonal, the number of paths from the lowest leftmost point to the highest rightmost point is given by 
$$2\binom {2n-1}{n-1} ^3$$

It can also be shown that for a similar configuration of $m$ attices each of dimension $n\times n$ and overlapping by one square along a common diagonal, the number of paths from the lowest leftmost point to the highest rightmost point is given by 
$$2\binom {2n-1}{n-1} ^m$$

Comment: I was sleeping, i see you did it for me, nice!

Comment: @Phicar - Thanks - glad you like it!

Answer (score 4):

Setting A in the origin $(0,0) $, we  must  necessarily  pass through either the point $C=(3,2)\, $ or the point $D=(2,3)\, \, $. Similarly, we  must also necessarily pass through either the point $E=(5,4) \,\,$ or the point $F=(4,5) \,\,$.

The pathways that cross $C $ and $E $ are $\binom{5}{3} \binom{4}{2} \binom{5}{3} =600 \, \,\, \,$, whereas those crossing $C $ and $F $ are $\binom{5}{3} \binom{4}{1} \binom{5}{3} =400\, \, \,$. So, a total of $1000$ paths pass through $C $. Due to the symmetry of the problem the number of paths passing through $D $ is equal. So we have a total of $2000$ paths.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: I got some of the numbers wrong below and am too lazy to fix them, but the general principle still applies.**

[image]

I'd do it the old fashioned way and just compute the number of paths to each point (by adding the number of ways to the points "west" and "south" of each node) until I reached B. I've done roughly half above.

Comment: This is called dynamic programming https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming