# Closed Form for Multiple Matrix Product

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, summation, binomial-coefficients

***(Revised for greater clarity)***

> Show that 
>   $$\underbrace{ \left[ \binom {n+1}{n-i} \right] }_
> {\mathbf{ v}\; 1\times n}\;\;
> {\underbrace{\left[\binom 2{1+i-j}\right]}_
> {\mathbf M \;n\times n} }^{(\lambda-1)(n+1)}
> \underbrace{\left[\binom {n+1}{n-i}\right]^T}_
> {\mathbf {v^T}\; n\times 1}\
> =\sum_{r=0}^{2\lambda}\binom {2\lambda (n+1)}{r(n+1)}(-1)^{r+\lambda}$$
>   where $i,j=0,1,\cdots (n-1)$;  $\lambda>1\ \ (\lambda \in\mathbb Z)$ and $n\geq 2 \ \ (n\in\mathbb Z)$.

This came up in the course of working out this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021406/lattice-walk-on-diagonally-overlapping-square-lattices).

For example, if $n=3, \lambda=2$  the equation above becomes
$$\underbrace{ \left[ \binom {4}{3-i} \right] }_
{ 1\times 3}\;\;
{\underbrace{\left[\binom 2{1+i-j}\right]}_
{3\times 3} }^{4}
\underbrace{\left[\binom {4}{3-i}\right]^T}_
{3\times 1}\
=\sum_{r=0}^{4}\binom {16}{4r}(-1)^{r+2}$$
i.e. 
$$\begin{array}  
= \big[\binom 43&\binom 42&\binom 41\big]
\\ \color{white}{\binom xx} &\hspace{0.1 cm}
\\ \color{white}{\binom 33} &\hspace{0.1 cm} 
\end{array}
\left[\begin{array}=
 \binom 21 &\binom22  &-         \\
 \binom 20 &\binom 21 &\binom22  \\
-          &\binom20  &\binom21  \\
\end{array}\right]^{\;4 }\;
\left[ \begin{array} 
&\binom 43\\ \binom 42\\ \binom 41\\ \end{array} \right]=\scriptsize\binom {16}0-\binom {16}4+\binom {16}8-\binom {16}{12}+\binom {16}{16}$$

Note that, if $\mathbf M$ is an **infinite matrix**, then 
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf M \mathbf v^T
&=\sum_{\text{all }i} \binom 2{1+i-j}\binom 4{3-i}=\left[\binom 6{4-j}\right]\\
\mathbf M^2 \mathbf v^T
&=\sum_{\text{all }i} \binom 2{1+i-j}\binom 6{4-i}=\left[\binom 8{5-j}\right]\\
\mathbf {vM}^4\mathbf v^T=\mathbf {vM}^2 \mathbf {M}^2\mathbf v^T
&=\sum_{\text{all }i} \binom 8{5-i}^2=\sum_{\text{all }i} \binom 8{5-i}\binom 8{3+i}\\
&=\binom {16}8
\end{align}$$
Hence the truncation of $\mathbf M$ gives rise to the alternating side terms.

---

$\\ \\ \\ \\$

***(Original question below - a bit wordy)***

Whilst working on this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021406/lattice-walk-on-diagonally-overlapping-square-lattices) the following matrix product emerged:

$$P=\underbrace{ \left[ \binom {n+1}{n-i} \right] }_
{\mathbf{ v}\; 1\times n}
\underbrace{\left[\binom 2{1+i-j}\right]^{m-2}}_
{\mathbf M \;n\times n}
\underbrace{\left[\binom {n+1}{n-i}\right]^T}_
{\mathbf {v^T}\; n\times 1}\qquad\qquad \cdots (1)$$
where $i,j=0,1,\cdots (n-1)$.

By putting $N=n+m-1$, and writing out the product in full for a few values, it appears that

$$\begin{align}
P&=\binom {2N}N-2\binom {2N}{N-(n+1)}+2\binom {2N}{N-2(n+1)}+\cdots\\
&=\color{}{\binom {2N}N+2\sum_{r=0}^\infty (-1)^r\binom {2N}{N-r(n+1)}}
\end{align}$$
where $\binom ab=0$ for $a<b$.

If $N=\lambda (n+1)$ where  $\lambda>1$ and $\lambda=\underbrace{\mu}_\text{integer part}+\underbrace{\delta}_\text{fractional part}$ then $P$ can be written as 
$$\color{}{P=\sum_{r=0}^{2\mu}\binom {2N}{(\delta+r)(n+1)}(-1)^{r+\mu}}$$
If $\lambda$ is an integer, then $\mu=\lambda, \delta=0$, hence
$$\color{}
{P=\sum_{r=0}^{2\lambda}\binom {2N}{r(n+1)}(-1)^{r+\lambda}
=\sum_{r=0}^{2\lambda}\binom {2(n+m-1)}{r(n+1)}(-1)^{r+\lambda}
=\sum_{r=0}^{2\lambda}\binom {2\lambda (n+1)}{r(n+1)}(-1)^{r+\lambda}}\qquad\qquad\cdots (2)\\
$$

> Is it possible to derive $(2)$ from $(1)$ directly?

---

NB - By putting $N=\lambda (n+1)=n+m-1$, we have $m=(\lambda-1)(n+1)+2$, hence $(1)$ becomes

$$P=\left[\binom {n+1}{n-i}\right]\left[\binom 2{1+i-j}\right]^{(\lambda-1)(n+1)}\left[\binom {n+1}{n-i}\right]^T\qquad\qquad \cdots (1)$$
where $i,j=0,1,\cdots (n-1)$.

Note that 
$$\mathbf M=\left[\binom 2{1+i-j}\right]=
\begin{array}
& && &i \\
&& &0 &1 &2 &3 &4 &\cdots &(n-2) &(n-1)\\
\hline
&&j &\color{orange}2 &\color{orange}1 &- &- &- &\cdots &- &-\\
&&1 &\color{orange}1 &\color{orange}2 &\color{orange}1 &- &- &\cdots &- &-\\
&&2 &- &\color{orange}1 &\color{orange}2 &\color{orange}1 &-&\cdots &- &-\\
&&3 &- &- &\color{orange}1 &\color{orange}2  &\color{orange}1&\cdots &- \\
&&\vdots\\
&&(n-2)&- &- &- &- &- &\cdots &\color{orange}2 &\color{orange}1\\
&&(n-1)&- &- &- &- &- &\cdots &\color{orange}1 &\color{orange}2\\
\end{array}$$